# migrating console application from VC 6 to VS 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, porting, visual-c++-6

i am migrating my project from vc6 to vs2010. while compiling i get an error at line

`TMemPool<T>::TTag* that error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*' along with error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int.`

can any one help me with this. i am sorry if i asked a dumb question. But i need help as i am not so good with coding.

Also if possible can you please tell me any pre-required settings needed to be done while migrating my project from VC 6 to VS 2010.  Plus is there any steps required to perform before migrating the code.

please find the line of code here for error. let me know if you need anything else.

thanks in advance.

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class T>
TMemPool<T>::TTag*
TMemPool<T>::GetAt
(
int I_Index
)
{
if(I_Index < 0 || (unsigned int)I_Index > GetTotal())
    return NULL;
return &m_pStorage[I_Index].m_Tag;
}

#endif // !defined(AFX_TMEMPOOL_H__825D671F_49E6_46C1_AB3D_79920EF692D8__INCLUDED_)
```

Comment: my guess, you are missing a semicolon after your `class{}` in the `.h` file.

Comment: Nope, that would cause a **duplicate** type specifier: `class Foo {} /*1*/template <class T> TMemPool<T>::TTag* /*2*/ TMemPool<T>::GetAt` - so does `GetAT`return a `Foo` or a `TTag` ? The problem here is that `TTag` does not name a type, as user93353 explains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type is `TTag`?

Try this

```
template <class T>
typename TMemPool<T>::TTag* TMemPool<T>::GetAt(int I_Index)
{
    if(I_Index < 0 || (unsigned int)I_Index > GetTotal())
        return NULL;
    return &m_pStorage[I_Index].m_Tag;
}
```

IIRC, VC6 used to compile stuff where `typename` was missing, but VC7 onwards, that changed.

Comment: Yup, VC6 cheated and instantiated `TMemPool<T>` to figure out what `TTag` would become.