# Including a visual c++ 6.0 header file in Visual C++ 2010 project

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a visual C++ 2010 project. I have two other old projects complied in Visual C++ 6.0 and I want to use these old projects classes in the new one. I was able to add one of the old projects successfully by setting the linker options, adding path in additional include directories and including the header file. I can create objects for classes and call methods successfully.
But for the second one, once I Include the project and build my solution in vc++ 2010, I am getting a lot of errors. The project compiles successfully in visual c++ 6.0.

Is there a way I can include this project successfully or Do i have to resolve each of these errors? I I see the errors growing as I keep resolving.

Thanks
R S

Comment: What sort of errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

If your old code had templates you may need to add typename in various places. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884759/migrating-console-application-from-vc-6-to-vs-2010)
You are almost certainly going to have to go through and deal with the errors one by one.